# Bootstrap Form Horizontal alignment issue when added input append

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am Trying to Create a simple basic form , I am unable to achieve Horizontal layout when added input-append class to the form , it kicks the second input box to be displayed in the same line ? wondering where the CODE ERROR is ? please suggest what is causing issue

```
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <hr/>

           <form class="form-horizontal">
            <!--<span class="offset2">Sign Into the Email</span>-->
               <div class="control-group">

                   <div class="controls"><span>Welcome to My Email</span></div>

                </div>

               <div class="control-group input-append">
                   <label for="emailid"  class="control-label">Email id</label>
                <div class="controls"> 

                    <input type="text" />
                   <span class="add-on">@</span>

                   </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="control-group input-append">
                    <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" />
                        <span class="add-on">***</span>
                     </div>
                </div>

               <div class="control-group">
                   <div class="controls"  >
                   <label class="checkbox">
                       <input type="checkbox" />Remember Me
                    </label>
                   <button class="btn">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </form>

        </div>    
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
        </body>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ? Are you looking for `form-inline` or `horizontal-form` ?

Comment: I am looking for horizontal form ONLY, when i strip of the "input-append" class and span tags i get the horizontal viewing but the moment i add the input-append class to the div the inputs arent aligning horizontally

Comment: I am sorry. The reason i asked what i asked was, Things looked fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zFmjG/

Comment: Karthik , You should look this pic , it seems to be okay but it doesnt , wonder why ? , see this - http://imgur.com/LRPjEXf

Comment: Now it get it :) Thanks. Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put the `input-append` in an inner `div`

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="input-append">
        <label for="emailid" class="control-label">Email id</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" /> <span class="add-on">@</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFmjG/1/)

`.input-append` has a `display: inline-block` Hence the issue

Comment: Absolutely Correct, Extra Burden of adding Div , Thanks you set an End to my Misery :)